# Parameter Accepting Generic List Type Object

Tags: c++, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I need to have a generic list type Object as a parameter ,which whenever accepts a different type of list object,pass that object in the function as converted list type object which was passed.
Is there any solution for this ,Please do help me

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: (List<T> obj){
if (obj is oftype <Books>)
//Convert that object to <Books> and do tasks
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to fully understand, but if you want your function to take a list of any object types as parameter, then you could use a generic method:

For C#:

```
private static void Foo<T>(IList<T> parameter)
{
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo<int>(new List<int>());
    Foo<string>(new string[10]);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Also do note that you can choose another interface/object than `IList`, depending on your needs (`ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, `List`...).